# Sportswear vs Sportsgear

Tags: differences

What is the difference in usage of those two words? For what I know, they both mean the same and somehow I couldn't find a dictionary entry for the word Sportsgear.

Sportsgear and seen in [this site](http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-gear/7puZbqt?ipp=120), is selling sports clothing. And sportswear pretty much means the same.

So, when and why in a few example scenarios would I use each particular word?

Comment: I don't see the word 'sportsgear' on the site you've linked to; and to be honest I don't ever remember seeing it anywhere.  'Gear', though, is widely understood to mean 'equipment', which may include 'sportswear' (specifically the clothing).

Comment: @JHCL it is in the title. If you hold your mouse over the tab for 2 seconds, you'll see the title which states: "Men's sports gear...." And my fitness coach has used this term quite a few times now, usually a reminder to bring some specific clothing in for the next session. So, I am wondering if there are any other scenarios to use this word to differ to sportswear.

Comment: _Sports gear_ is a phrase; as far as I kknow it does't get used as a word, the way _sportswear_ does. Having said that, I agree with other posters that _sports gear_ is a wider term, encompassing clothing and other equipment.

Answer (score 1):

The website provides an answer.

When clicking on gear, it shows socks, hats, watches, and backpacks.

When clicking on sportswear, it shows pants, shirts, shorts, socks, and other items of clothing.

Gear is equipment used for a purpose.  Xwear (winter wear, sportswear, swimwear, etc) are items of clothing worn.  Some may disagree but I don't feel "gear" can be used to talk about pants, or underwear.

Comment: The question is about the *word* 'sportsgear'; I've still not seen any sign that it's actually used anywhere, to any extent. The meaning of the phrase 'sports gear' is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THESE?
**Sportsgear** or **Sports Equipment** are object used in sports(e.g. flying disc/discraft, cleats, weight lifting belts, etc) while **Sportswear** are garments worn casual outdoors (e.g. apparel) especially people intending outdoors/sports.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You answer would be more useful if you could provide examples that support your claim, as otherwise, it may be seen as your personal interpretation. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance on submitting good answers.